# How Do I pass the result of a variable in this vb app?

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

I have written the piece of code below to calculate factorials of numbers more than or equal to 1.

```
Public Class FactorialApp

    Private Function FactorialChecker(myNumber As Integer)
        myNumber = Val(FactorialTextBox.Text)
        If myNumber < 1 Then
            FactorialChecker = 1

        Else
            FactorialChecker = myNumber * FactorialChecker(myNumber - 1)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub ResultButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResultButton.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

I want to have a message box in a `button_click` event that says something like **The factorial of 5 is 120** when clicked where 5 is supposed to be `myNumber` and 120 the `FactorialChecker()` function, but I have no idea how to return values in VB's `MsgBox` command, I'm only used to C#'s .

I tried the code snippet

```
    MsgBox("The Factorial of  + myNumber "is" + FactorialChecker() "")
```

But I got stomped by syntax errors in visual studio and also an error that my `myNumber` variable wasn't declared in the program. What can I do to fix these errors please?

Comment: I'm assuming the missing quotes and + signs in the snippet are just typos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
MsgBox("The Factorial of " + myNumber + " is " + FactorialChecker())
```

You just didn't close your quotes for the first part of the string so they're unbalanced, thus your compiler errors. Also, I added some spaced because I assume you'll want them.

Note that in VB.NET, using `MessageBox.Show` is preferable to the old VB6-style `MsgBox` function.  Also, in VB, the `&` operator is typically recommended over the `+` operator for string concatenations, since the `+` operator can have some unexpected results when you have `Option Strict Off`.  So, this would be the better way to do that:

```
MessageBox.Show("The Factorial of " & myNumber & " is " & FactorialChecker())
```

Comment: +1 for edit mentioning `&` over `+` for string concatenations.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the tip. Just one more problem, I keep getting the error **myNumber is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.** in visual studio.

Comment: @FeyisayoSonubi I believe the error is saying `myNumber` does not exist in the scope you're trying to use it. Most likely, `myNumber`'s scope is within the `FactorialChecker()` function but you're using it outside of that. So make sure you declare the variable and set it to some value before this line of code. Also, I think you're going to pass it to the `FactorialChecker` function.

Answer (score 1):

For a first attempt, move `myNumber = Val(FactorialTextBox.Text)` into your button Click handler. If you reload it every time your FactorialChecker function is called, then your recursion won't work the way you want it to.

Also, you're not declaring it or specifying a type, so you may want to change that line to `Dim myNumber As Double = Val(FactorialTextBox.Text)`. Then below it, add the `MessageBox.Show` call, as others have said.

`Val()` may not be a good choice, since it returns a Double, and the factorial function is defined only for non-negative integers. You probably actually want `myNumber` to be an Integer (or a Long, or something else, depending on the range you need). You could then replace `Val()` with `CInt()`, or `Integer.Parse`, or `Integer.TryParse`, and add error-checking to make sure the value is non-negative.Integer.TryParse, and add error checking to make sure the value is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

`myNumber` is declared inside the `FactorialChecker` function.  If you try to access it outside that function it won't exist.  You might need to make it a property of the class.